# i am getting this error '' Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" im using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id,pwd from users where Id=@Id and pwd=@pwd", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox2.Text;
con.Open();
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
    dr.Read();

    if ((dr["Id"].ToString() == TextBox1.Text) && (dr["pwd"].ToString() == TextBox2.Text))
    {
        Session["signing"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("UserAccueil.aspx");
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = dr["Id"];
    }
    else
    {
        Label3.Visible = true;
        Label3.Text = "Incorrect mot de passe/Email";
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: i'm getting this error because i want to display the name of a user on my website, please help me!

Comment: Why do you have 2 lines `Label1.Visible = true; Label1.Text = dr["Id"];` in your code? They make no sense after `Response.Redirect`, because the user will be redirected to a new page anyway. If you remove these 2 lines you should not be getting an error

Comment: @dotnetom, what i want is to display the name of the user on it own page once he will be redirected to it. in the label1's properties, i made visible=false in the front end for the label1, so in order to display the id , i hve used the first line label1.visible=true,....i hope you understand.

Comment: This is not how ASP.NET works. If you are redirecting user to a new page using `Response.Redirect`, no changes are made to the old page, only redirect happens. So you can safely remove the 2 code lines after `Response.Redirect`, because they are pointless

Comment: ok thanx for the advice. now how can i Display the name of the user on it page by retrieving it from the sql server database???

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you assign an object to the Text property of type string:

```
Label1.Text = dr["id"];
```

In order to solve it, either use the GetString method (the index of the column is 0) or ToString:

```
Label1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
```

Or

```
Label1.Text = dr["id"].ToString();
```

Comment: @larie it would be very helpful if you could point out the line. Is it the same error?

Comment: label1.Text=dr['id']

Comment: @larie did you change the line as described in my answer?